# Estimate original matrix from matrix multiplication result

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, signal-processing, image-processing

Let $A$ be $m \times n$ real matrix.
Let $B$ be $n \times k$ real matrix.
Let $C= A \times B$ ($m \times k$ matrix).
Now, the question is: given $C$ and $A$, give an estimate for $B$.
Possible estimate is $B_{\text{estimate}} = A^T × C$.
Is there a way to interept this as best estimate? (Assuming ($A^TA$) not necessarily invertible). ($B$ can be thought as image representation).

Comment: Start by thinking about extreme cases (e. g n=m, m= and so on). Also consider the pseudo inverse of a matrix.